# SQL select all items where team_id is ( 1 and 2 and 3 and 4 and .. rest values from list)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I try to select items where team id = list of values;
For example :  list of values is (9,7,6,4,3,1)
and I want to create query select with item who have team_id = (9,7,6,4,3,1);

My try :

```
select item_id
from t_item as i join
     team as t 
     on t.item_id = i.id
where t.id in (1221, 1219, 1);
```

But it working likes `in (1221 or 1219 or 1)` but i want `in(1221 and 1219 and 1)`

Comment: @lucumt, why wouldn't it be. Say item is "protective hat", teams are "soccer, volleyball, american football, baseball, hockey, basketball". "protective hat" is used by "american football AND baseball AND hockey". But say an item like baseball bat is only used in "baseball".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want `group by` and `having` as well:

```
select i.item_id
from t_item as i join
     team as t 
     on t.item_id = i.id
where t.id in (1221, 1219, 1)
group by i.item_id
having count(distinct t.id) = 3;
```

Note that you do not need the `join`:

```
select t.item_id
from team t 
where t.id in (1221, 1219, 1)
group by t.item_id
having count(distinct t.id) = 3;
```

And if the rows in `team` are unique, use `count(*)` rather than `count(distinct)`.